# Delegate : method name expected

Tags: c#, interface, delegates

```
interface IDrawable{
    void Draw();
    double ReturnArea(Delegate del);
}


public double ReturnArea(Delegate del){
       return del();
}
```

`del()` is highlighted and I am receiving `"Method name expected"`. Basically my question is how can i get this interface method to take as argument delegate which let me use whatever functionality they will provide in methods?

Comment: Use a Func<double> instead of Delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn´t specify the delegates return-value or its parameters. When using `Delegate` the actual methods signature isn´t known at compile-time. Thus when *invoking* it, there´s no way for the compiler to infer the right types, neither for the return-value nor for its arguments. Thus you could provide *any* delegate to your `ReturnArea`-method. Thus even the following would be valid:

```
ReturnArea(() => Console.WriteLine("this method doesn´t return anything"));
```

However when you know the actual types at compile-time, there´s no reason to stay on the generic `Delegate`. You can use a strongly-typed delegate instead, e.g. `Func<double>`:

```
interface IDrawable
{
    void Draw();
    double ReturnArea(Func<double> del);
}

//...

public double ReturnArea(Func<double> del)
{
   return del();
}
```

If you really need to use the generic approach with `Delegate` you have to write this instead:

```
public double ReturnArea(Func<double> del)
{
   return del.DynamicInvoke();
}
```